# c# HttpResponseMessage.Content length is 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have own api where i upload bytes to stream and equate Response.Body to it. And when my another contoller from another app receive response there is 0 length stream. I suggest it null stream though headers content is the way i need. I couldn't find answer, maybe i need to more google.

```
public async Task<ImageModel> GetImage(int id, int width = 1, int height = 1)
    {
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        HttpRequestMessage req = null;
        HttpResponseMessage resp = null;
        try
        {

            req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, getUrl);

            var headers = req.Headers;
            headers.Add("id", id.ToString());
            headers.Add("width", width.ToString());
            headers.Add("height", height.ToString());

            headers.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
            resp = await client.SendAsync(req);


            var name = resp.Headers.GetValues("name").FirstOrDefault();
            var size = int.Parse(resp.Headers.GetValues("size").FirstOrDefault());
            var ext = resp.Headers.GetValues("extention").FirstOrDefault();
            var sizeX = int.Parse(resp.Headers.GetValues("width").FirstOrDefault());
            var sizeY = int.Parse(resp.Headers.GetValues("height").FirstOrDefault());


            ImageModel model = new ImageModel();
            model.Id = id;
            model.Name = name;
            model.Size = size;
            model.SizeX = sizeX;
            model.SizeY = sizeY;
            model.Extention = ext;

            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                model.Stream = await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                var bs = await resp.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            }



            return model;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string m = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            resp?.Dispose();
            req?.Dispose();
            client.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

It's where make request.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        var headers = Request.Headers;
        int id;
        int height = 1;
        int width = 1;


        var idStr = headers["id"];
        var heightStr = headers["height"];
        var widthStr = headers["width"];


        var res1 = int.TryParse(idStr, out id);
        var dbImg = await _db.Images.FindAsync(id);

        var res2 = int.TryParse(heightStr, out height);
        var res3 = int.TryParse(widthStr, out width);

        if (!res1)
            return BadRequest();
        if (!res2 || height <= 0)            
            height = dbImg.SizeY;
        if (!res3 || width <= 0)
            width = dbImg.SizeX;



       
        var rHead = Response.Headers;

        rHead["name"] = dbImg.Name;
        rHead["size"] = dbImg.Size.ToString();
        rHead["extention"] = dbImg.Extention;


        var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        string resHeight;
        string resWidth;
        if (height != dbImg.SizeY || width != dbImg.SizeX) {

            var img = Image.Load(dbImg.Bytes);
            img.Mutate(x => x.Resize(height, width));
            img.Save(memStream, new JpegEncoder());

            resWidth = img.Width.ToString();
            resHeight = img.Height.ToString(); 

            img.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            resWidth = dbImg.SizeX.ToString();
            resHeight = dbImg.SizeY.ToString();
            memStream = new MemoryStream(dbImg.Bytes);
        }

        rHead["width"] = resWidth;
        rHead["height"] = resHeight;

        Response.Body = memStream;
        
        
        
        return Ok();
    }
```

It's my api method

Comment: Where did you find this code? It is a good example how not  to write  http requests and responses. Google and find a modern http client code pattern. You are using net core , not webforms 3.5.

Comment: The reason you're not getting data is because you're returning `Ok()` from the action. From IntelliSense: "Creates a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkResult object that produces an **empty** Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status200OK response."

Comment: Serge, can you write my mistakes. I'd change it